# Почему из-за изменения стилей input в состоянии focus не отрабатывает addEventListener("submit")

Tags: javascript, input, css-animation, submit, focus

В состоянии focus высота поля Message увеличивается. Если нажать кнопку send, пока message в фокусе - событие submit(click тоже) не отработает. При повторном(втором) нажатии - сработает.
Такой эффект появляется, если при состоянии фокуса **любому полю** изменить высоту. И пропадает если убрать изменение высоты.

```
&_textarea:focus {
      height: 90px;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка работала при первом нажатии? [Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/marinary/pen/yLeEJMY)
[image: форма]

Comment: Скорее всего в момент нажатия кнпока уезжает из под мышки, и событие `click` не срабатывает.

Comment: да, это была моя первая идея, но нет. кнопка на месте. и проблему, как оказалось, можно решить при помощи события mousedown, которое отрабатывает. но все еще не понятно, почему такое вообще возникает. и это mousedown - какие-то пляски с бубном. почему так? почему не submit или click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае это действительно из-за ухода кнопки из под мышки.

1. В момент нажатия кнопки мыши фокус уходит с инпута
2. инпут меняет высоту
3. кнопка сдвигается
4. если курсор мыши не над кнопкой не происходит события `mouseup` и, как следствие `click`
5. из-за этого не происходит отправка формы.

---

Для решения нужно либо зафиксировать высоту, чтобы при уходе фокуса высота не менялась

либо откладывать выполнение обработчика на какое-то время.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но можете пожалуйста подтвердить правильно ли я вас понимаю? В момент нажатия по кнопке(событие mousedown) - фокус исчезает - кнопка меняет положение и событие mouseup уже на кнопке не отрабатывает, так как она переместилась в другое место страницы? Поэтому и click - тоже не отработает потому что click по сути сочетание mousedown + mouseup. А раз нет клика по кнопке, то нет и submit?

Comment: @Marina, примерно так

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поймать щелчок над кнопкой, при изменение высоты соседних элементов в фокусе, нужно использовать событие mousedown для кнопки.
Событие **mousedown** срабатывает, когда кнопка указывающего устройства (к примеру, мыши) нажата над элементом.

Например:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
   alert("вы попытались нажать кнопку");
})
```

Comment: Не надо использовать событие mousedown Для этого, так как оно для другого предназначена, плюс ломается стандартное поведение, когда ты можешь нажать кнопку, увести курсор в сторону и отжать - в этом случае клика не произойдет